# Hyperledger Fabric CA Tool not generating identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy a production Hyperledger Fabric network on kubernetes and when trying out the example from fabric-ca sample, I can see that the pod running fabric-ca-tools is not generating and giving an error at line number 51 from setup-fabric.sh in function `registerOrdererIdentities` where the ORDERER is registered with CA for identity using command `fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ORDERER_NAME --id.secret $ORDERER_PASS --id.type orderer. It fails to register and says,`Error: Response from server: Error Code: 0 - Registration of 'orderer1-org0`failed: Identity 'orderer1-org0' is already registered`
.

I am not able to understand, that if the identity was not previously registered by root-ca and intermediate ca then why this error is coming.

Stuck here from a long time, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Had anyone faced the same issue or is it something, I am missing here??

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown whenever you try to re-register an identity which is already registered. So that means you have already run fabric-ca-client register command for --id.name orderer1-org0. The next step would be you enrol orderer1-org0 with the appropiate password and in return you will recieve certificate and private key. from CA server.The interesting part is, now I am searching a way where I can edit attributes of already generated certificate. Kind of like edit it at the first place. But I keep getting this error. For a moment I though that revoking the certificate will make it work but nonetheless that only made a requirement to run fabric-ca-client reenroll Unable to find any help anywhere.